# How do I get the aggr result over a limited size of result instead of the entire index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with over 80k records and want to find average for the most recent 50 records. I cannot find the query to use aggr with size parameter. Please help.

Comment: Aggregations apply to the query that you specify. You could try querying for date range and then aggregating over the results, or nesting your aggregation under a date range aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html

Comment: Thank you so very much. 
 
Aggregations apply to the query that you specify.  >> solved my issue